# Possible minor typo from Dummit's Abstract Algebra

Tags: number-theory, integers

On page 4, 0.2/(4)/(b) of Dummit&Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (3rd ed.):

> (If $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, there is a unique positive integer $l$, called the *least common multiple of a and b* ... satisfying:) if $a\mid m$ and $b\mid m$, then $l\mid m$ (so $l$ is the least such multiple).

May I ask if it is necessary to assert "*so $l$ is the least such **positive** multiple*" there? (since there also exist $l\mid m$ such that $m\leqslant 0$)

Comment: Since $\ell$ was specified to be unique in the class of positive multiples, I think that *such multiple* can safely be understood to mean *positive integer multiple* (of $a$ and $b$).

Comment: It seems you've already answered your own question with the observation that the negative LCM is smaller than the LCM.  So what question remains to ask here?

Comment: +1 assumed that you intended "...(since there also exist $l | m$ such that $l \leq 0$)" Technically yes, reasonable to specify that $l$ is the least such **positive** multiple.  Informally, the author intended that only positive integers $l$ be considered, re his phrasing: "unique positive integer $l$..."

Comment: @JakeMirra For readers new to the subject, it is reasonable to be paranoid about whether the author made a technical oversight.

Comment: @user2661923 JakeMirra BrianM.Scott Thank you all, I thought "*such multiple*" was referring to $m$ not $l$

Comment: I think the entire phrase "(so $l$ is the least such multiple)" was meant to be an aid to intuition and an explanation of why $l$ is called "least common multiple," but is not actually part of the formal definition of the LCM. The definition could simply have stopped after $l\mid m.$ If anything is missing, it's the phrase "for any integer $m$".

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for mentioning that :) yes, *least/greatest* could be one of corollaries but need not to be in the rigorous definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to highlight that:

> there is a unique **positive** integer

Here it's clear enough. And as what you said in the problem description, you already comprehended it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The reason for me to ask this question is because if we treat "*such multiple*" as $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, the proposition would still hold. But anyway I think it is down to how I interpret the language, not the math

Comment: I see. Your modification is good and surely makes that clearer, but as a textbook, you can't require every detail of it to be exhaustive. XD